# page focus when hash does not exist on load

Tags: javascript, html, hash, onload

a link with a hash to my page,

```
http://www.mydomain.com/somewhere/page.html#somehash
```

does not align itself correctly because the ID `somehash` does not exist in the uploaded `page.html`.  the ID is created by in the `onload` script and added through the DOM.  the ID does not exist on the page until that part of the `onload` script has completed.

moving within the page using different hashes works fine, since all the ID's are already in place.

how do I instruct the browser to re-align (as versus reload) itself at the end of the `onload` script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end of the `onload`

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
window.location.hash = '';
window.location.hash = hash;
```

this seems to work ok

Answer (score 1):

Try this after element is added

```
    var hash = location.hash;
    if (hash && hash.substr(1).length) {
        var hashLink = document.getElementsByName(hash.substr(1))[0];
        if (typeof(hashLink) != 'undefined' && hashLink.offsetTop != 'undefined') {
            window.scrollTo(0, hashLink.offsetTop);
        }

    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UJ5DX/2/

Comment: pretty sophisticated.  think you have small bug in that the hash can be the name of an anchor or the id of any element - seems you're skipping the id part.  think found simpler method - posted as answer.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to scroll the page to the corresponding hash.

```
function scrollToHash(hash) {
    var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++) {
        var lnk = allLinks[i];
        if (lnk.name == hash) {
            console.log("dd");
            i = allLinks.length;
            var desty = lnk.offsetTop;
            var thisNode = lnk;
            while (thisNode.offsetParent && (thisNode.offsetParent != document.body)) {
                thisNode = thisNode.offsetParent;
                desty += thisNode.offsetTop;
            }

            window.scrollTo(0,desty)

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that will set the hash...OP wants to focus on element that hash represents after it is added to DOM

Comment: @ATOzTOA `window.location.hash=='somehash'` when the page is loaded - it's part of the URI (URL?).  resetting it to 'somehash' does nothing because it does not change its value.

Comment: changing the hash will not cause browser to scroll to element the same way it does when page loads or when clcik on internal link

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadingstuff(){
    //stuff
    location.href += "#somehash";
}

window.onload = loadingstuff;
```

This will focus on the newly added element.